# Is there a backend table like plan_table?

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-administration, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

Is there a backend table like plan_table where we can see the output of autotrace, similar to explain plan output? Like if I am running a long query with autotrace and by chance, the session gets logged off while reading the autotrace output and I want to see again the autotrace output without running the long query.

Answer (score 1):

No, what we do is we check the before and after session stats coming out of v$sesstat.

Options:

1. Check V$SQLSTATS which contains some metrics for sql execution.  This also gives the SQL_ID for this query, which leads to
2. You *might* be able to glean some information from v$active_session_history if you are licensed for it using the SQL_ID
3. You can run a SQL Monitoring report (see DBMS_SQLTUNE) with the SQL_ID you got from (1). This information lingers for a while in memory.

Comment: when using the AutoTrace in SQL Developer (if you observe the Statements log panel), you can see us querying v$ stats views for data before and after running your query...